# Login strategy on Xamarin forms an Azure

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I am using the ADAL3 for authenticating on the Azure AD app. Then I use the AuthenticatedClient Async for logging into the Azure backend.

What is the correct strategy for consuming Azure backend and working with token? Do you call AuthenticateClientAsync before each call to the backend to be sure that if the session expires on the backend the token will be used to start the session automatically? What append if the memory save token is expired, do you manually ask users to login again?

Someone has a sample of an app that popup a login page then call some service and popup a new login page if needed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) would be the approach for you to work as your mobile backend. And you could authenticate your customers with AAD and leverage the client SDKs provided by Azure Mobile Apps to communicate with your azure mobile app backend.

I would recommend you follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started) for creating your Azure Mobile App and download the sample project for getting started. Then, you could configure your mobile app to use AAD login, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users). Moreover, more details about how to use the client SDKs for Azure Mobile Apps in your xamarin project you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library).

> Someone has a sample of an app that popup a login page then call some service and popup a new login page if needed?

After logged via `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync`, you would retrieve a JWT token issued by your mobile app backend and you could get it by accessing `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken`. And you could cache the token for reusing it. You could wrap the operations against your mobile app backend and catch the exception when the token is expired and manually call `LoginAsync` to ask the user for logging again or validate the token in your client side and re-login if the token is invalid before you send requests to your mobile app backend. For caching the token and validate the token, you could follow adrian hall's book about [Caching Tokens](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/#caching-tokens). For wrapping the table operations, you could follow [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already got an Azure C# backend running well. But Thanks for your link for wrapping table operations, I will implement that. But The Caching Token does not work for now.  I am on .netStandard 2.0 (not a PLC) so the Xamarin.Auth is not available for now. The ADAL3.0 take care of the refresh token automatically, so I am not sure if I can use Xamarin.Auth the same way. For now that work well in UWP and Android, ADAl3 keep the user logged between app restarting, but not in IOS11.

Comment: Based on your comment, I assumed that you are using the [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow). The Caching Tokens I mentioned before is used for the server flow authentication to cache the `authenticationToken` issued by azure mobile app backend. For your scenario, you could just leverage ADAL to handle the cache and retrieve the latest` authenticationToken` when your app starting, but I have no idea about why it does not work in iOS11.